# Add section only in TOC

Tags: latex

Is it possible in Latex to insert a section only in the table of contents but not display it on the corresponding page?

Comment: This will depend on the documentclass. Try `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Quack!}` or add a [mre]

Comment: Thank you very much this solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most document classes, you can add entries to the toc via

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Quack!}
```

Comment: I have one more question. Is it also possible to continue numbering with the command?

Comment: @Gurkenkönig It would be much easier to guess what you are asking if you would make a [mre] and also explicitly state which section should be numbered how